# Racial representation in Epic Fantasy

Tags: fantasy-races

This is my first time posting. Let's see if I can do this without being eaten alive.

I am trying to understand how to offer more representation to under-represented groups in a fantasy novel, without sounding racist. I know there are plenty of threads on similar topics, but let's see if I can explain my dilemma. In a lot of blogs about creative writing, people are 'blamed' for highlighting the racial distinction of a person. Example: "almond-shaped eyes". This is incorrect because Asian don't have almond-shaped eyes, and also I read a lot of comments like: "why do you have to highlight that they are Asian? why don't you describe them with the way they move, or talk instead of focusing on physical appearance." This sounds legitimate to me, but it leaves me with the dilemma: how do I offer wider representation of under-represented groups in fantasy genre, if I cannot describe them physically? are we saying we should just write fantasy without races? or with all non-human races? (I am not setting the novel in Asia, or Siberia or North-America, so i cannot lead readers to imagine how people would look based on the country)

Links to things that haven't helped me:

- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-tastefully-describe-the-Asian-shaped-eyes-of-a-fictional-character-without-sounding-racist-and-related-to-this-how-would-I-describe-Asian-toned-skin-and-avoid-the-same-concerns)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/writing/comments/3f8psm/what_are_some_goodrespectful_adjectives_to/)
- [npr](https://www.npr.org/sections/codeswitch/2013/09/16/219402847/-almond-shaped-eyes-remarkably-exotic-yet-too-foreign?t=1605882648130)

Thank you.

(P.S. if someone could also offer an alternative to 'almond-shaped eyes' that doesn't sounds like out of a medical book, I'd be eternally grateful, thank you.)

Comment: Almond shaped eyes are not an exclusive property of "Asians", whatever Asians may be. First, *people move around,* and you will find people of mixed "racial" heritage almost anywhere. For example, here in Romania lives a Hungarian-speaking population called [Székelys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Székelys), some of whose ancestors came from Central Asia about 1,000 years ago. To this day, some children are born with almond eyes; which we the round-eyed find quite attractive. Second, many decidely non-Asian populations have "[slanted eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicanthic_fold)".

Comment: Are you basing your races on any existing racial or ethnic groups or there would be no traceable parallels? Anyways, if your question is about _descriptions_ of races (rather than actual features), i think it's better suited for Writing SE.

Comment: Hi, thanks. the almond-shaped eyes was an example...there is no such thing as 'asians' or anything like that in my book. I dont understand the different between description and features. Im talking about physical features. No links with cultural traits. I dont what what 'Writing SE' mean. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I mean [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/). I'm saying  that it appears that your question is not about whether to give your race elongated eyes but rather how to describe them tactfully.

Comment: ah i see! thank you, ill ask there too!

Comment: yeah, i have to be honest, this doesnt seem like it fits here exactly since its more about writing than creating a world

Comment: What are almond shaped eyes? I can only find stuff like this: https://i2.wp.com/amberrosebeauty.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/piceye1.jpg?resize=327%2C623&ssl=1 where I cannot tell the difference between "almond" and "round".

Answer (score 7):

### Make it plot specific.

I think one of the largest mistakes made by writers of fantasy, is the addition of racial characteristics without a clear plot reason. The reason people make jokes about Netflix adaptions is because of sloppy writers find a reason to focus the story on a racial/sex/gender identity without having a reason to by plot. So, the issue is not the racial representation, but making the writing around the "token black guy" rather than the amazing character who happens to be black. When people were complaining about a darker skinned "Little Mermaid," it wasn't about the skin color, it was about the need to change a completely irrelevant part of the story for representation. If you want a great character, make them matter. Make their lives, culture, race and experience all matter to the reader for one reason or another.

### Describe your environemt.

Use race to your advantage to tell something about the place, setting, or culture which your story is presenting. For instance: dark skin is an adaption for high-radiation/solar environments. Light skin, for light starved environments. Maybe in your example with almond eyes, make it relevant by saying how "the long years of staring at a far horizon" have pronounced the wrinkles or lines on a face. In many fantasy settings, people add details, such as: a low level of tech and transportation (leading to racial/cultural tribes), many planets (with different species), ideological splits (wizards vs. dwarves), etc. Only include the details when they paint a picture that describes your world, not to appease or cajole. Your audience will see the difference and appreciate it.

### Have  fun.

Sometimes, just sometimes, a character doesn't fit with any story convention, but it's advantageous to describe them to add flesh or interest to the story. When you plan your characters, DON'T plan them based on race. Plan their actions, then as you write, let them come alive. Play with them. Change their race or gender for fun, to see where it goes. Enjoy the story, and the audience will enjoy it too.

Comment: thank you very useful. Something that i struggle with is this plot-driven obsession: I assume that someone's behaviour is born out of personal experiences. no link for me between someone having blue eyes and the lore of the specific race. (unless they are equipped with different organs) are we saying, that we are going beyond the physical description of fantasy faces? does this mean we are not describing their physique, because how could their eye shape be possibly plot-relevant? are we just defaulting, assuming, that each reader will then imagine the character physically similar to their own?

Comment: Absolutely! I think it can be relevant to add racial characteristics for the plot...after all, most racial groups developed because of environmental constraints or genetic shift because of culture separation. For an example of how eye shape can be relevant: in 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea, Jules Verne uses the wide, Indian eyes of Captain Nemo to describe his ability to scan the entire horizon...and to be able to see everything going on behind his back when keeping Professor Aronnax from escaping.

Comment: thank you, yes of course it makes sense. it's just it feels like we always need to 'justify' why a race would have certain physical traits in our stories when they are not defaulted to 'white', while the white race never seem in need of any explanation....

Comment: You are right. I'd avoid that though. What made star wars so great, in my opinion, was its ability to weave completely alien species into a story that seemed totally normal within the universe. No one explained Chewbacca or Huttese speech, they just roared, everyone understood, we all grasped the concept of an alien with alien language. In Attack the Block, the default people group and language was Black British street gang, they were the default. It's all in the frame you present your story in. If you are drawing on Euro fairy tales with elves and witches, of course europeans are default.

Answer (score 2):

**Ethnically Inspired Names go a Long Way.**

Say you have a book written in the third person. You want to include (quite specific) Ethnic diversity but avoid coming off racist by having the narrator say "Oh and by the way Min Zhu has almond shaped eyes". (what are almond shaped eyes by the way?)

Moreover suppose the story is written from Arnold's point of view, and Arnold is [NOT A RACIST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zkL91LzCMc&list=PLQTAXw5ECeFIqAAzys4D3Uu51GBgOifDe). The first time he meets  Min he cannot help but notice her appearance and ethnicity. But mentioning it in the narrative makes it sound like an important thing to him, which we don't want to do (remember [NOT A RACIST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zkL91LzCMc&list=PLQTAXw5ECeFIqAAzys4D3Uu51GBgOifDe)). But we still want to give that information to the reader. What  can we do?

The trick is to not mention it explicitly. Hint at it. Arnold introduces himself to Min. He has difficulty pronouncing her second name. He goes to shake her hand and she is obviously not practiced at this sort of greeting. They talk about her long trip from the the distant Empire of Bae-Sei. She remarks on the humidity here and how people look at her funny. She wants to buy some more nondescript clothes, something more suitable for the weather. And what's up with you guys drinking cold water all the time? Drinking cold stuff is bad for your health don't you know?

Immediately we get an impression of someone who is from far away and visually sticks out. Also her name and Country of origin are obviously Asian inspired. It is obvious to the reader that "THIS CONTINENT IS THE ASIA OF MY WORLD". Their imagination does the rest.

To really drive home the point, have a drunk passerby walk up to Min Zhu and say something rude about her appearance. This gives that information to the reader without putting a value judgement on it. Or rather it gives the information to the reader and also says "By the way this is a bad thing and little physical differences like this shouldn't be mentioned in polite society."

A less agressive option is that later on Min goes to the market to buy some clothes. There is an overzealous seller who insists *This* shade of red looks beautiful against her sallow skin and dark hair and she *must* buy it. This guy is a bit of an ass but his shtick is "You are better because you are different" compared to the drunk guys "You are worse".

Comment: "To really drive home the point, have a drunk passerby walk up to Min Zhu and say something rude about her appearance. This gives that information to the reader without putting a value judgement on it. Or rather it gives the information to the reader and also says "By the way this is a bad thing and little physical differences like this shouldn't be mentioned in polite society." THIS IS SUCH A WONDERFUL IDEA! you really got my point. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Provide a reason *in the story* why describing the character's appearance would be relevant to the plot.

To use a fantasy-style example, let's say there's a scene where the antagonist is explaining to her minions that the caravan they are attacking has one particular person they're supposed to capture, who is a visitor from a distant land, but possibly traveling in local-looking clothes to try and blend in as much as possible. The minions, not being very worldly types, have no idea what people from that distant land look like, and the caravan has people from a number of different places, so the antagonist can't simply say "Grab the one who looks different". She'll have to provide some description.

> "Look for the one with dark skin, dark brown, almost black, eyes, and tightly curled black hair."
>
> One minion scratched his head. "Dark like skin like a tanned farmer? My cousin Hegeth is dark like that."
>
> "No idiot, I mean dark as in almost black."
>
> The minion looked up, startled. "There are people who look like that?"

Of course, if you want to play with the trope:

> "Look for the one with light skin, blue eyes, and light yellow hair."
>
> The minion looked up, startled. "There are people who look like that?"

Just, I beg of you, *don't* have the character contemplate their appearance in a mirror. Unless they've physically transformed into a different appearance (a possibility in fantasy/sf settings), no one outside badly-written characters does that.

Comment: "don't have the character contemplate their appearance in a mirror" haha I promise i wont. thank you for the other suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You have an **epic fantasy** setting. Presumably it does not have *African-Americans* or *Africans* or *Indians* or *Chinese*. Does your setting have distinctive races/ethnic human subgroups at all?

- If humans are at least as mobile as they were in the Roman Empire, and if they *genuinely do not care* about race for a couple of generations, then they should look fairly homogenous after a few dozen generations. Describe a world where other clues indicate social status. Have people being obsessed about accents, and manners, and show them trying to pretend an upper-class accent.
- If there are visibly distinct ethnic groups, think of fictional characteristics. Like blue hair. Amber eyes. Pointed ears. You'd probably have to do some thinking and googling to avoid any *existing* racial stereotypes.
- Assume that visible distinctions exist, and that *most* people don't care. Every now and then a bad guy does, and gets characterized as a villain. This gives you the opportunity to show after a few chapters how diverse the good guys are. Of course there is a danger of appearing tacky if you overdo the reveal.

Comment: thank you: "If there are visibly distinct ethnic groups, think of fictional characteristics. Like blue hair. Amber eyes. Pointed ears. You'd probably have to do some thinking and googling to avoid any existing racial stereotypes." this is brilliant. but allow me the question: is let's say a race had horns...are we defaulting that race to be white because we are in fantasy? why can;t they be blue skinned and with horns? or have almond-shaped eyes and have horns? (devil's advocate here but im interested in your opinion)

Comment: @Kaleidoscope50 not them but thats really 100% up to you, and would seem to just be a matter of opinion

Comment: @Kaleidoscope50, when we talk about human *races* we talk about differences within the species *homo sapiens sapiens*. Humans have dark skin, light skin, and all shades in between. All are interfertile and there has been no speciation (google that term). With horns, would it be the same or would people either have horns or not? If you want to make a point about inclusivity, shouldn't your differences be equally cosmetic and gradual? Pointy noses, flat noses, pointy ears, flat ears, hair colors, let some people fuss about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just write exactly what you want to write. It is your story and the only thing that you need to worry about is writing something that people will enjoy reading.
There will always be people ready to complain about *anything* (just ask a publisher), just ignore them. Such complainants have no moral authority whatsoever, so do not feel that you have to grant them any.

Comment: thank you very much! it's a very nice encouragement!